# src of image loading

Tags: javascript, src

In html file I have something like this:

```
<img src="dist/assets/img/photos/md/photo-1.jpg"/>
```

And then with JS I check window width and change the path of the image accordingly to something like:

```
<img src="dist/assets/img/photos/xs/photo-1.jpg"/>
```

or

```
<img src="dist/assets/img/photos/lg/photo-1.jpg"/>
```

The question is, for xs window does it load only xs-sized image or both - the md (because I have md path in html) plus xs-sized image from js?

Thank you.

Comment: Once the js executes, the request for the medium image is probably already sent. You should be able to verify that in the network panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the **md** file will be loaded and as soon as the *JavaScript* will load, the **xs** will also be loaded, and the `<img>`'s source will be changed to the **xs** file's path.

Answer (score 0):

The medium image could be loaded but you have no guarantee on that. Indeed, the javascript can change the `src` attribute value almost as soon as the *DOM* is ready. The request of external resources like images does not block the firing of the *DOM ready* event.

Because browsers do pretty agressive optimizations, the request for fetching the medium image will be probably already sent. In case of (relatively) high network latency, the request will still be pending when the script will change the attribute value, otherwise, or if the image is already in cache, it will be already loaded.

NB: For tackling the problem of responsive images, the `srcset` attribute might interest you. It depends of [what browsers you should support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) though.

Comment: Michael P. Bazos, thank you for the answer! Yee, the thing is that I need to support IE10..